# Get searching value from INI file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ini

I have an INI file that i was wondering if i could get a value from with this givein information

my INI looks like this

```
[Images]
image135=Lava.bmp
x135=13
y135=5
image76=Mountian.bmp
x76=7
y76=6
image86=Lava.bmp
x86=8
y86=6
image85=Lava.bmp
x85=8
y85=5
image125=gryph.bmp
x125=12
y125=5
```

now I open this ini, and i want to find the image##[value] Where all I know is  x##[value] and y##[value]

So Say I know my values are (8,6)   Now i would like to get the image Lava.bmp returned. Note 8 is x coords, 6 is y coords.

not sure if iam explaining this right but if not please ask for more info

CURRENT CODE

```
HexMapIni := TIniFile.Create(FGamePlay.MapName);  //creates ini file
eposition.x := FGameplay.TempCurrentPosition.x;  //x value to search ini for
eposition.y := FGamePlay.TempcurrentPosition.y;  //y value to search ini for
ImageYouWant := //Searchresult.bmp
Hexmap1.ImageAHex(ImageYouWant , bsSolid, eposition);  //place image on map
```

Comment: That is what i had thought, but was hopeing there was a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function GetBitmap(Ini: TCustomIniFile; X, Y: Integer): String;
begin
  Result := Ini.ReadString('Images', Format('image%d%d', [X, Y]), '');
end;
```

Comment: not sure how this works , but ill give the function a try as soon as i get home.

Comment: It works like: Search for `'imageXY'` in front of the `'='` sign, and return what's after. This is pretty default ini functioning.

Comment: haha, i didnot notice the xy was the number after 'image' :D thanks

Comment: @NGLN: Nice catch - I didn't notice that the X/Y were also the values after 'image'. +1.